# Make sure the text doesn't break the line

Tags: css, reactjs

Make sure my text doesn't break a line inside a < ul> < li> < a> tag
Basically I have a dropdown menu and I want the items in that drop down not to break the line and have a padding in my < li> tag:

code:

```
export const DropDown = styled.ul`
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 29px);
  right: auto !important;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;

  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  li > a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li {
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    :hover {
      background-color: #e5e5e5;
      color: white;
    }
  }
  li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
`;
```

**jsx**

```
<DropDown>
          {dropdownItems.map(item => (
            <li>
              <a href={item.link}>{item.name}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </DropDown>
```

at the moment I have this:

[image]

I need to continue with the padding and I didn't want to set a width

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/drop-down-menu-egrti

Comment: Try adding `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: @ZohirSalak thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `white-space:nowrap;` to your `DropDown` styling and also set its `right` to 0;

```
export const DropDown = styled.ul`
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 29px);
  right: 0 !important;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  white-space:nowrap;
```

Comment: I need my container to be centralized with my li

Comment: @gabriel I just mentioned that because in the codepen the drop-down was going off screen. If you do not need it so not set it. The important stuff is the `white-space`